# Reorder list based on multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to change a data.frame in R from this

```
Sample Protein Value
a      TBA     10
b      TBA     5
a      TBB     30
b      TBB     20
```

to this

```
Protein a  b
TBA     10 5
TBB     30 20
```

How do I do this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can probably use ``dcast()``. 
``dcast(data,
      Protein ~ Sample)``

Comment: I suggest you take a look at some R Studio cheat sheet for such questions. Those can really help you understand those functions. You can go there : https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/

Answer (score 1):

Try `dcast` from `reshape2`:

```
df <- data.table::fread('Sample Protein Value
a      TBA     10
b      TBA     5
a      TBB     30
b      TBB     20')

dcast(df, formula = Protein ~ Sample)
```

Output:

```
  Protein  a  b
1     TBA 10  5
2     TBB 30 20
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df1, Sample, Value)
```